# bash script for simple inventory database

Tags: shell-script

for an exercise I need to create a simple bash script where I can add or remove items to an inventory file.

The requirements are the following:

> **each item can have the following properties**
>
> - ID (mandatory)
> - date added (mandatory)
> - name (mandatory)
> - type (mandatory)
> - notes
> - date removed

> **adding an item**
>
> - reads item properties “name”, “type”, and “notes” from the command line and
> - generates “ID” and “date added”
> - adds the new item to the inventory

> **removing an item by ID**
>
> - sets the date it was removed
> - keeps it from being shown in the inventory listing

> **the inventory listing shows the following columns**
>
> - ID
> - type
> - name
> - date added
> - notes
> - date removed (if you implement the functionality to show removed items)

This is what I did:

Create a file called **database**

```
touch database
```

Create a file called **inventory.sh**

```
echo
echo Please select one of the following options:
echo
echo 'a = Add a record'
echo 'b = Delete a record'
echo 'c = Show inventory'
echo 'd = Exit database'


echo
        read choice

                case $choice in
a) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/add_record.sh;;
b) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/del_record.sh;;
c) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/list_record.sh;;
d) exit;;

*) echo Invalid choice - Bye.

                esac
```

Create a file called **add_record.sh**

```
echo Please enter item name:
read item
echo

        grep -q $item /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/database
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo ERROR -- Item $item already exist
        echo
        exit 0
        fi


echo Please enter item type:
read type
echo

echo Please enter Description:
read description
echo

echo "ID:$RANDOM" "NAME:$item" "CATEGORY:$type" "NOTES:$description" "Date added:$(date)" >> database

echo "The provided item has been added"
echo

echo
echo Please select one of the following options:
echo
echo 'a = Add a record'
echo 'b = Delete a record'
echo 'c = Show inventory'
echo 'd = Exit database'

echo
        read choice

                case $choice in
a) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/add_record.sh;;
b) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/del_record.sh;;
c) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/list_record.sh;;
d) exit;;

*) echo Invalid choice - Bye.

                esac
```

Create a file called **delete_record.sh**

```
echo Please enter ID or the itemname you want to delete?
read item
echo

        grep -q $item /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/database
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo
        sed -i '/'$item'/d' /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/database
        echo $item has been deleted
        else
        echo Record does not exist
        fi

echo
echo Please select one of the following options:
echo
echo 'a = Add a record'
echo 'b = Delete a record'
echo 'c = Show inventory'
echo 'd = Exit database'

echo
        read choice

                case $choice in
a) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/add_record.sh;;
b) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/del_record.sh;;
c) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/list_record.sh;;
d) exit;;

*) echo Invalid choice - Bye.

                esac
```

Create a file called **list_record.sh**

```
clear
cat /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/database  

echo
echo Please select one of the following options:
echo
echo 'a = Add a record'
echo 'b = Delete a record'
echo 'c = Show inventory'
echo 'd = Exit database'

echo
        read choice

                case $choice in
a) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/add_record.sh;;
b) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/del_record.sh;;
c) /home/dagobert/Desktop/Assignments/A8/list_record.sh;;
d) exit;;

*) echo Invalid choice - Bye.

                esac
```

Adding and removing an item works like charm, but one requirement doesn't match.
If I remove an item it's completely gone from the file database instead of keeping the record.

How can I improve the script that a removed item will still persist in the file database and the date of removal will be added to it?

Thanks in advanced for every help and suggestion
FreeRunner

Comment: If you delete a record you can't capture the date it was deleted. Perhaps you could change "delete a record" to "mark a record as deleted", and see if that helps

Comment: You say you want to keep the deleted record, yet you delete the entire line: `sed -i '/'$item'/d' /.../database`. Instead, you should add a column with the deleted date, e.g. `sed -i '/'$item"/s/\$/ Date deleted:$(date)/"` (not tested). Of course, you will have to add code to `list_record.sh` to omit items that have a delete date.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks for your suggestion. I did add a new entry to mark an item as delteted and keep it in the database file. Your sed command worked for me :) Thanks for your help